# php mysql update database on button click

Tags: php, html, mysql

as the title states I am trying to write a code that will update a boolean data in column (I called 'status') for a specific row. I used while loop in table to display the rows of new registered and where the status is NULL, I've put two buttons (accept, reject) each in td so they'll be displayed to each name, What I want is when the accept button clicked, it sets the status of its row in the table to 1, and when reject is clicked, same thing but sets 0 instead of 1.

I've did a lot of research over this but hit a road block after road block, so I really hope your help in this, many thanks!

Here is my code:

```
<table id="sHold" style="border:none;">

<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'srs-db') or die('ERROR: Cannot Connect='.mysql_error($conn));

    function getStudent () {
        global $conn;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE status IS NULL;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        $i = 1;

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $sId = $row['student_id'];
            $sName = $row['student_name'];

            echo "<tr id='sNew".$i."'>";
            echo "<td>".$i." - </td>";
            echo "<td>$sId</td>";
            echo "<td>$sName</td>";
            echo "<td><button name='sAcc".$i."'>Accept</button></td>";
            echo "<td><button name='sRej".$i."'>Reject</button></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $i++;
        }
        if (isset($_POST['sAcc'.$i])) {
            $row['status'] = 1;
        }
    }

    getStudent();

?>

</table>
```

Comment: why is $i used outside of the loop?

Comment: @Gacek I put it inside the first time, but the number did not increment, so I put it outside and it worked fine

Comment: You need to use AJAX to send a request to the server when the user clicks on a button. The request should contain `$sId` from that row, and whether they clicked `Accept` or `Reject`. Then the AJAX server script can do `UPDATE student_table SET status = ? WHERE student_id = ?`

Comment: You'll need to learn Javascript if you don't already know it.

Comment: The code is missing a lot. You need a `form` to post data to the server or some javascript to send Ajax requests. Read more about form handeling for PHP to understand more.

Comment: @user3586095 Yes. But it will only work for *last* entry. All earlier entries will be ignored. Since it's executed after you exit loop.

Comment: @Barmar Don't think he needs to do it with ajax. don't complicate it to him. He first needs to learn how forms, submission and form handling works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you miss `<form>` element. Your form inputs are useless without it, or without ajax.

Secondly, your `$_POST` check will only check last item. Since after you exit loop `$i` is set to last value in the loop. So your example will only work on last item.

`<button>` will now send `$_POST` with one of indexes `sAcc` or `sRej`. And it's value will be ID of your entry.

```
<table id="sHold" style="border:none;">
<form method="post" action="">
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'srs-db') or die('ERROR: Cannot Connect='.mysql_error($conn));

    function getStudent () {
        global $conn;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE status IS NULL;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        $i = 1;

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $sId = $row['student_id'];
            $sName = $row['student_name'];

            echo "<tr id='sNew".$i."'>";
            echo "<td>".$i." - </td>";
            echo "<td>{$sId}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$sName}</td>";
            echo "<td><button type='submit' name='sAcc' value='{$sId}'>Accept</button></td>";
            echo "<td><button type='submit' name='sRej' value='{$sId}'>Reject</button></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $i++;
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['sAcc']) && intval($_POST['sAcc'])) {
        $user_id = (int) $_POST['sAcc'];

        // Do the database update code to set Accept
    }
    if (isset($_POST['sRej']) && intval($_POST['sRej'])) {
        $user_id = (int) $_POST['sRej'];


        // Do the database update code to set Reject
    }



    getStudent();

?>
</form> 
</table>
```

`Tip:` I assume you're beginner. I remade your code. But you dont need to put this code into function. Use functions to handle data retrieval for example. Dont use it to display html.

Comment: Thank you so much sir!! You're a life savior cuz I needed this for a project that's the deadline is this Sunday. Also you're assumption is in its place, I am a beginner indeed in PHP. I'm only using it cuz it's the best option for my project where working with databases

Comment: can you explain what was done here and for future visitors to the question/answer? and why their code was failing them in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table id="sHold" style="border:none;">

<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'srs-db') or die('ERROR: Cannot Connect='.mysql_error($conn));

    function getStudent () {
        global $conn;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student_table where status='NULL'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        $i = 1;

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $sId = $row['student_id'];
            $sName = $row['name'];

            echo "<tr id='".$sId."'>";
            echo "<td>".$i." - </td>";
            echo "<td>$sId</td>";
            echo "<td>$sName</td>";
            echo "<td><button name='sAcc' id='acc-".$sId."' onclick='approveuser(this.id)'>Accept</button></td>";
            echo "<td><button name='sRej' id='rec-".$sId."' onclick='approveuser(this.id)'>Reject</button></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $i++;
        }

    }

    getStudent();

?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function approveuser(id){

     trid=id.split('-')[1];
     //alert(trid);

    $.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
        type:"post",
        data:{ val : id },


        success: function(result){
            //alert(result);
            $('table#sHold tr#'+trid).remove();
            alert('Updated');

    }
    });
}
</script>
//The code give below this update.php pge(ajax page)
<?php
$data=$_POST['val'];
$status =explode('-',$data);
$user_id=$status[1];

if($status[0]=='acc'){
    $value=1;
}
elseif($status[0]=='rec'){
    $value=0;
}

  $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'srs-db') or die('ERROR: Cannot Connect='.mysql_error($conn));
 mysqli_query($conn,"update student_table set status='$value' where student_id=$user_id");

?>
```

Comment: Ajax method without refreshing the page

Comment: This answer is not injection safe or generally stable because prepared statements are not used.